# Present simple about past

Tags: grammaticality

Donald Trump said:

In the good old days this **doesn’t** happen because they used to treat them very, very rough. And when they protested once, you know, they would not do it again so easily

Why didn't he say?

In the good old days this **didn’t** happen because they used to treat them very, very rough. And when they protested once, you know, they would not do it again so easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Donald speaks in mysterious ways but I will try to interpret his words.  The context is key.  I've found your quote with a *See* that precedes it:

- See! In the good old days this doesn’t happen, because they used to treat them very, very rough...

Trump is addressing a crowd attending a political campaign rally and protesters are being expelled from it, they're being escorted out, which presumably is taking some time, all eyes are on them.

The *See!* and the *this* clearly refer to the scene people are watching.  They root what he's saying in the present time and trump the *In the good old days* that should trigger the use of the past tense.

It's an oddity from a strictly grammatical standpoint but easily understandable from a pragmatical one.